# AllowSynchronousIO set to true, but still getting exceptions

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, io

I have an output formatter that formats my message to XML and adds some content) using XSLT.

```cs
        public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                string xml = GetXMLFromObject(context.Object);

                var accept = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"].FirstOrDefault();
                response.ContentType = accept;

                var templateFile = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Template"].FirstOrDefault();
                ExcelProvider.ConvertToStream(templateFile, xml, response.Body);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I have both IISServerOptions and KestrelServerOptions configured to enable SynchronousIO

```
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });
            services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });
```

However, when I send a request, I get an exception

```
fail: Project.Api.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware[0]
      Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream.Flush()
   at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.Close()
   at System.Xml.XmlRawWriter.Close(WriteState currentState)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.Close()
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.Dispose()
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, Stream results)
   at Project.Common.ExcelProvider.ConvertToStream(String templateFile, String data, Stream stream) in /src/Project.Common/ExcelProvider.cs:line 28
   at Project.Api.Formatters.ExcelOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context) in /src/Project.Api/Formatters/ExcelOutputFormatter.cs:line 34
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.OutputFormatter.WriteAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Project.Api.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in /src/Project.Api/Middleware/ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 24
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM2OMURFR65H", Request id "0HM2OMURFR65H:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpHeaders.ThrowDuplicateKeyException()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpHeaders.System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<System.String,Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>.Add(String key, StringValues value)
   at Project.Api.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex) in /src/Project.Api/Middleware/ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 42
   at Project.Api.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in /src/Project.Api/Middleware/ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 29
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

I have no clue what I need to change. Am I doing something wrong? My app is dockerized and I run it via `docker-compose up`

```
version: '3'
services:
#mssql docker
  project-sql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=QWElkj132!
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    ports:
      - 1401:1433
    networks:
      - projectnet

  project-api:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings:FitBody=Server=project-sql,1433;Database=FitBody;User=sa;Password=QWElkj132!;ConnectRetryCount=0
    ports:
      - 58744:80
    networks:
      - projectnet
    links:
      - project-sql
    depends_on:
      - project-sql
      
networks:
  projectnet:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `docker-compose up --build` has been the proper "fix" for this. That should rebuild everything as Docker tends to use what it already has so even if you change something, those changes may not be present.